# TcpInboundGateway: How to close existing connection with remote client

Tags: spring-integration

I am using TcpInBoundGateWay to receive messages from remote clients.But problem is that clients change their IP's at regular intervals.So if one of the client is communicating through IP 'X', then gateway will have connection with that IP now when that client's IP is changed from 'X' to 'Y' then new connection is established with that IP at the same time old connection with IP 'X' is active. So now I have around 10-15 client communicating to this gateway but if i do `netstat -all` it gives as 2000-2500 connection established with that port.

Is there any way so that I can terminate that old connection?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class SpringIntegrationApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    DataOperations dataOperations =new DataOperations();

    @Value("${TCP_PORT}")
    private Integer TCP_PORT;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringIntegrationApplication.class, args);       
        System.in.read();
        ctx.close();
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringIntegrationApplication.class);
    }

    private static Class<SpringIntegrationApplication> applicationClass = SpringIntegrationApplication.class;


    @Bean
    TcpNetServerConnectionFactory cf(){
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(8765);

        connectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);

        return new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(TCP_PORT);
    }

    @Bean
    TcpInboundGateway tcpGate(){

        TcpInboundGateway gateway=new TcpInboundGateway();
        gateway.setConnectionFactory(cf());
        gateway.setRequestChannel(requestChannel());
        gateway.setRequestTimeout(20000);
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel requestChannel(){

        return new DirectChannel();
    }
}
```

List of connection from `netstat` commnd

```
tcp6       0      0 ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.u:10189 106.221.201.180:15076   ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.u:10189 27.58.41.100:41965      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.u:10189 106.221.136.178:39192   ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.u:10189 106.221.135.124:2271    ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.u:10189 27.58.57.252:31644      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.u:10189 27.58.33.219:32134      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.u:10189 106.221.218.22:17275    ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.u:10189 27.58.172.42:30130      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.u:10189 27.58.21.127:16998      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.u:10189 27.58.60.160:51374      ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These clients are badly behaved.

You can `connectionFactory.setSoTimeout(...)` and the connection will be closed if no data is received in that number of milliseconds.

Alternatively, `connectionFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true)` will cause the Operating System (or more properly the TCP stack) to send pings to detect these dead connections and close them. The actual time between keepalives is configured at the operating system level, but they must be enabled on the socket, which is what this option does.

See the [javadocs for Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html).

Google SO_TIMEOUT and SO_KEEPALIVE for more information.

**EDIT**

To explicitly close a connection, the connection factory has a method...

```
/**
 * Close a connection with the specified connection id.
 * @param connectionId the connection id.
 * @return true if the connection was closed.
 */
public boolean closeConnection(String connectionId) { ... }
```

... you can can obtain a particular connection id from a message from the client (in header `ip_connectionId`) or when the connection is opened via the `TcpConnectionOpenEvent`. You can also get a list of currently open connection ids:

```
/**
 * Returns a list of (currently) open {@link TcpConnection} connection ids; allows,
 * for example, broadcast operations to all open connections.
 * @return the list of connection ids.
 */
public List<String> getOpenConnectionIds() { ... }
```

Comment: is there any custom way to terminate particular connection

Comment: The connection factory has a method (see the edit to my answer).